# Cannot implicitly convert from Anonymous type to generic List

Tags: linq-to-sql, return, anonymous-types

Three Tables:

```
Category - CID, CName,CParentID (when CParentID=0, its a Category; when CParentID > 0, its a SubCategory)
Product - PID,Title, Desc etc
Category_Product - CPID, CID, PID
```

Function:

```
        public List<T> GetProductCategory<T>(int id)
    {
        var Query = from ProductTable in objProductDataContext.Products
                             join CPTable in objProductDataContext.CategoryProducts on ProductTable.ProductID equals CPTable.ProductID
                             join CategoryTable in objProductDataContext.Categories on CPTable.CategoryID equals CategoryTable.CategoryID where ProductTable.ProductID==id
                             select new { ProductTable, CPTable, CategoryTable };
        return Query;
    }
```

I need to return this data to the controller. How can I do this? I read about creating a separate class, but I am not sure how I would do it in this case. The heading is the current error I am getting.

Comment: what is the use of T in the query. U need to return Query.ToList() and in select new should be eqaul to T.

Comment: how do I make select new equal to T?

Comment: Create a `T`, not an an anonymous type. Also, you return IQueryable, not a List.

Comment: Make a class (say ProductCategory) Which has Properties for ProductTable, CPTable, CategoryTable . and in select write like  new ProductCategory(){ ProductTable=ProductTable,CPTable=CPTable,CategoryTable=CategoryTable}.And use this class instead of T, Return Query.ToList(). You can NOT return Anonymous Type from a function.